# Have non-wordpress page as root (and blog elsewhere)

Tags: installation

I'd like to have a custom, non-Wordpress page (totally separate HTML/CSS/etc. files) at www.mywebpage.ca, and then my Wordpress blog only at www.mywebpage.ca/news. Is this possible?

(The reason for this is that I'd rather write the more complicated layouts from scratch for my entry page, and then have Wordpress's content management on the news page only.)

Thanks for reading!

Comment: Have you looked at [Giving WordPress its own directory](http://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory)?  You can also use [Page Templates](http://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates) to do more complicated and custom layouts.

Comment: I agree with [Andrew](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/17879/andrew-bartel) and also suggest reviewing this post for how to access WordPress functionality from other PHP files http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/170467/custom-php-file-in-wordpress/170468#170468

Comment: Install Wordpress in its own directory. You can read more about it here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory
https://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-install-wordpress-in-subdirectory

Comment: Thanks for the comments. The template approach could be ideal, @AndrewBartel, but getting the design into Wordpress has been a little troublesome (http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/172741/css-acting-differently-in-and-out-of-wordpress). The "Pointing your home site's URL to a subdirectory" section in the linked article above may be a solution, as my non-wordpress page could go in the directory and users could be redirected there from the root directory. Thanks!